Aligning item to background
On the page below, when I resize the page horizontally, the building image is aligned to the background image perfectly. However, when I resize the page vertically, the building is not aligned in the same manner. What shall I do?
https://www.ortakalan.org/code/bg4.htm
Thanks in advance.
This CSS aligns the building to the background when the page is resized horizontally. I am expecting the same behavior when the page is resized vertically.
.building
{
    width:max-content;
    left:-100vh;
    right:-100vh;
    top:20vh;
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.background_container
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: url(Classroom1.png);
    background-position: center;
}


it seems as if you are just missing a dynamic height and bottom position for the "building" element. Try setting height: max-content and bottom: 20vh and it should work.
.building {
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
  left: -100vh;
  right: -100vh;
  top: 20vh;
  bottom: 20vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

